# I'm working with Python4Delphi and in PyEnvironment packages "

Tags: python, delphi

I'm working with Python4Delphi and in PyEnvironment packages and I get the following error:

> [dcc64 Fatal Error] Unit2.pas(8): F2051 Unit PyEnvironment was compiled with a different version of PythonEngine.TPythonEngine

I have downloaded both the Delphi4Python package and the PythonEnvironment from "git clone"

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "git clone"? If it is what it sounds like, how about downloading from the "original" `github.com` instead.